# I am a holder of a UK Spouse Visa. Can I stay in the Schengen Area for longer than three months on the basis of my Spouse Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

My husband and I separated in May though divorce proceedings are not through yet, so I am currently still the holder of a UK Spouse Visa. I would like to go stay with friends in Germany for a few months - not work there, just have a prolonged sort of holiday which I have enough savings to afford. Would it be legal for me to stay in Germany for longer than three months on the basis of my UK visa?

Answer (score 5):

No, it would not be legal. UK is not part of Schengen area, you cannot cross the border of any Schengen country on basis of your UK visa.

See also here [Schengen Visa Requirements for UK spouse](http://schengenvisaservice.weebly.com/visa-for-uk-spouse-to-travel-to-europe.html).